# How to show that all trajectories of this dynamical system end in a disk?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider the system:

$$\begin{alignat}{2}
   x_{1}' &=&~ -ax_2 &+ x_{1}\left(1-x_{1}^2-x_{2}^2\right),\\
   x_{2}' &=&   ax_1 &+ x_{2}\left(1-x_{1}^2-x_{2}^2\right)-b,
 \end{alignat}
$$ where $a,b$ are real numbers. The task is to show that there is a disk which eventually contains every orbit of the system and that there is a limit cycle only if $b$ is zero.

Up to this point, I was trying to construct a function $V(x_1,x_2)$ with negative derivative along the solution curves on a disk but it’s not getting anywhere.

Maybe a proof by assuming the opposite plus a theoretical argument would do the job, but I would welcome any hints here.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the question that you were asked. Hyperbolic limit cycles can't exist for only one parameter value: they exist for an open interval, maybe a small interval, but it's still an interval, not just a single point. Even if you plot phase trajectories in WA you will see that there is a limit cycle in the system for small values of $b$.

Answer (score 2):

Really $V(x_1,x_2)=x_1^2+x_2^2$ does everything. Writing $r^2=x_1^2+x_2^2$ we get
$$
\frac12\frac{d}{dt}V(x_1,x_2)=r^2(1-r^2)-bx_2
$$
and so for $r$ very large this is negative: it is approximately equal to $-r^4$ (and also $|x_2|\le r$).

For the second question see the comments by Evgeny.

Comment: I might be missing something, but for $b \approx 0$ there must be a limit cycle. There is a limit cycle at $x^2 + y^2 =1$ when $b=0$, it is hyperbolic and it can't just disappear instantly.

Comment: It is $r'=r(1-r^2)-b\sin\theta$. Why do you say that it is hyperbolic?

Comment: The first Lyapunov value can be computed pretty easily in case when $b = 0$: if you have a periodic orbit $(\xi(t), \chi(t))$, then the first Lyapunov value (or linear part of return map) can be computed by formula $\exp{\left ( \int\limits_{0}^{T} \left ( P'_x(\xi(t), \chi(t)) + Q'_y(\xi(t), \chi(t)) \right ) dt \right )}$. I've computed it and got something like $\exp{(-4\pi)}$, so the multiplier is definitely less than 1 and limit cycle is hyperbolic.

Comment: I see, that's good, I assumed that the question of the OP was correct and answered only noting that that part needed also to be address (in addition to my answer to the first part). The last sentence is now erased.

Comment: @Evgeny: Could you explain what $P'_x$ and $Q'_y$ are?

Comment: @MrYouMath I suppose that you have a system of ODEs $\dot{x} = P(x, y), \; \dot{y} = Q(x, y)$. And in that case $P'_x$ and $Q'_y$ are just partial derivatives (sorry if $\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial y}$ is more correct way to denote them).

Comment: @Evgeny: Thank you! I was guessing that it would be something like this. Do you know any reference to this topic?

Comment: @MrYouMath I'm afraid not an English one, but I'm pretty sure that it must be covered in other books too. For example, Kuznetsov also refers to this formula [in these slides](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~kouzn101/cm/L1.pdf), so maybe you can start from his teaching materials. First time I've encountered this formula in Russian book _Качественная теория динамических систем на плоскости (Леонтович, Андронов, Гордон, Майер)_ (it seems that there is an [English translation](https://www.amazon.com/Qualitative-theory-second-order-dynamic-systems/dp/0470031956)).

Comment: @Evgeny: Thank you for the references. Great stuff :D.

Answer (score 2):

Using polar coordinates,$\ x_1=r\cos(\theta )$ and    $ \ x_2=r\sin(\theta )$ transforms the system  $$x_{1}'=-ax_2+x_{1}(1-x_{1}^2-x_{2}^2)$$ $$x_{2}'=ax_1+x_{2}(1-x_{1}^2-x_{2}^2)-bx_2 $$ into $$r'=(1-r^2)r^2-bx_2$$ $$\theta '=a-bx_1/r$$Note that $$r'=(1-r^2)r^2-bx_2= -r^4+ r(r-b\sin(\theta ))          $$ Thus if we consider a disc with  a large enough radius, r' will be negative and the trajectory stays in the disc.

For $b=0$ we get $r'=0$ at $r=1$, which makes $r=1$ a limit cycle.

On the other hand For $b\ne 0$, $ r'$ depends on $\theta $ and there is no limit cycle.

Comment: Actually *there is* a limit cycle. You can easily construct a trapping annulus using the formula for $r'$. This limit cycle is not a perfect circle though.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was thinking limit circle . You are correct of course.